# ElasticSearch Aggregation Past _source

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

I am trying to get a list of all possible article groups.  My Product array example is like so:

```
[8] => Array
                        (
                            [_index] => product_index
                            [_type] => product_51_DEU
                            [_id] => AV7mxnScT3P3M-G9u9aK
                            [_score] => 1
                            [_source] => Array
                                (
                                    [artikelnummer] => G123456
                                    [produktname] => My Cool Name Here
                                    [artikeltext] => BLA 
                                    [produktgruppe] => Car Products
                                    [anwendungsbezeichnung] => Wash Products
                                    [lieferant] => Turtle
                                )

                        )
```

My PHP search parameter looks like this:

```
$mainMenuParams = [
    'index' => 'product_index',
    'type' => 'product_51_DEU',
    'body' => [
        'aggs' => [
            '_SOURCE' => [
                'terms' => [
                    'field' => '_source.produktgruppe'
                ]

            ]
        ]
    ]
];
$listProduktGroup = $GLOBALS["client"]->search($mainMenuParams);
```

I get an answer but there are no aggregations. I have tried many combinations, but none seem to work. Anyone have any idea where this is wrong? I want to see an aggregation  with an output of all of the possible  [produktgruppe]. There are 10 Groups in all, but it would be nice to see this in the results and then maybe even a count of all products in each group.

If I do the exact same query on "_types" I get accurate results.

Comment: Simply remove `_source.` from the term `field``

Comment: Doesn't work. That actually crashes the query. I thought the same too

Comment: 100% sure that `_source.` needs to be removed in all cases. What error do you get?

Comment: Can you show your mapping? i.e. what you get from `curl -XGET localhost:9200/product_index /_mapping/product_51_DEU`

Comment: Mapping: {"product_index":{"mappings":{"product_51_DEU":{"properties":{"anwendungsbezeichnung":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"artikelnummer":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"artikeltext":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"lieferant":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"produktgruppe":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}}...

Comment: Well then you don't have any index called `product_index`, so your query cannot return anything.

Comment: Thank you Val, but that is not correct. The problem is something else

Comment: Thanks for the mapping. You should use the `produktgrup‌pe.keyword` field instead otherwise you'll have issues with fiedldata. that'll work

Comment: Man I had hope for that one as it made sense. [aggregations] => Array
        (
            [_SOURCE] => Array
                (
                    [doc_count_error_upper_bound] => 0
                    [sum_other_doc_count] => 0
                    [buckets] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

        )

Comment: 'field' => 'produktgrup‌pe.keyword'

Comment: how many docs do you have in in your index? Are you sure you've setup your client properly (i.e. hitting the right server?)

Comment: there are only 90,000 docs in the index. This Agg should return a result of maybe 25 different terms. Maybe a few more. It works with _type just fine though.

Comment: It seems there is a difference between the '_type' field and the '_id' field for example. I can aggregate the _type field but not the _id. With that I wonder if the same problem exists with the produktgruppe filed as the _id field?